# Laravel namespace issue after adding a folder under Models

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models in Laravel 5.5 under the **"Models**" folder. I then created a folder called **"Internal"** inside the Models folder and inserted my models in that folder. I updated all the namespaces and also did `composer dump-autoload`. But I now get an error that states that

> "Class 'App\Models\Internal\LeaveApplication' not found".

Here is the Controller namespace:

```
use App\Models\Internal\LeaveApplication;
use App\Models\Internal\LeaveType;
```

Here is the model's namespace:

```
namespace App\Models\Internal;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Comment: I mean that the folder has the same casing as the namespace. `internal` vs `Internal` (folders and namespaces are case sensitive)

Comment: Have you update this in `comoser.json` file?: `"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "database",
    "app/Models/Internal",
  ],`

Comment: @HirenGohel - Doesn't Laravel 5.5 use PSR-4? Then you shouldn't need to add any classmap, since the top namespace `App` already is registered.

Comment: I am ask to just check in composer!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I more than triple checked all casing, so that is not the problem. I'm quite baffled about this one

Comment: Ok. Btw, where do you get that error? It seems like it's asking for `Class::url`? That's not one of your models, right?

Comment: The error is on browser, I did not copy full URL, but here it is: Class 'App\Models\Internal\LeaveApplication' not found

Comment: @horcrux88: Please create model like php artisan make:model Internal\yourmodelname and try

Comment: @horcrux88 Have you created those models using artisan command OR manually?

Comment: can you run this: `composer dumpautoload` ? did it change something?

Comment: @HirenGohel I created them using Artisan command and then renamed it. But it worked after I renamed it. Then I moved it into the folder.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I have run composer dump-autoload several times

Comment: did you update the path in controllers?Show us your controller code. @horcrux88

Comment: @horcrux88 I think you need to try with artisan command where you want to create models and when you renamed file, make sure you need to update class name also! If possible, don't place directory again and again to place models. Do run again artisan command and Hope this works!

Comment: Can you debug `vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php` method `loadClass` to see if PSR4 is trying to locate the class?

Comment: Like @HirenGohel said I would also recommend to try the artisan command `php artisan make:model Internal\LeaveType`